# Counting total interactions per user

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to show the "Censored" interactions by user by day and total Censored by user.

```
select
date("PostedAt"),
"UserId",
sum(count(*)) over(order by("PostedAt")) as "Total by User"

FROM
"CommunityPost"
WHERE
"Censored"=true
GROUP BY "PostedAt","UserId"
ORDER BY ("PostedAt") DESC
```

which outputs the total for all users in this group, not total by UserId.

```
Date.         UserID Total by User
"2020-04-22"    41  12
"2020-04-22"    41  11
"2020-04-22"    32  10
"2020-04-21"    32  8
```

How do I get total by UserId?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `PARTITION BY`. Example is given below:

```
SELECT
DATE("PostedAt"),
"UserId",
SUM(count(*)) OVER(PARTITION BY "UserId", "PostedAt") AS "Total by User"
FROM
"CommunityPost"
WHERE
"Censored"=true
GROUP BY "PostedAt","UserId"
ORDER BY ("PostedAt") DESC
```